# Access control for each Tables with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, admin, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

For example I have two tables accessed by SonataAdminBundle

now I would like to change the editable tables depending on user roll

Manager(ROLL_Admin) ->  can edit both tables
User(ROLL_User) -> can edit only Item table.

```
services:
    sonata.admin.user:
        class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Manager Editable, label: "User" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
            - 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD'
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeAdminBundle]]
    sonata.admin.armarket:
        class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\ArMarkerAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: User Editable, label: "Item" }
        arguments:
```

Is it possible??

I know secutiry.yml offers the access control for each url though, 
I think this is a bit defferent from security.yml layer.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup sonata to use security voters [link](http://www.branchbit.be/blog/using-custom-voters-in-sonata-admin)

This will allow finetuning over who gets to access what